# IList grouping then create new listarray

Tags: c#, list

there have a IList<> have 12 elements，

now，i make the ilist around a circle,end-to-end，

then grouping this list every three element a group，but The beginning of the next group is the end of the previous group，like this：

[0][1][2],[2][3][4],[4][5][6],.......[10][11][0].

how can i make this succeed,the c# will be better

Comment: Use AddRange() instead of Add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    foreach (var b in Batch(list))
    {
        foreach (var n in b)
            Console.Write(n + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static IEnumerable<IList<int>> Batch(IList<int> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 2)
    {
        var batch = new List<int>();

        for (int j = i; j < i + 3; j++)
            if (j < list.Count)
                batch.Add(list[j]);

        int count = batch.Count;

        for (int j = 0; j < 3 - count; j++)
            batch.Add(list[j]);

        yield return batch;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is what i want,thx